# Google Script - Email certain rows of a sheet into the body of email

Tags: google-apps-script

everyday we copy cells A1:D20 from our sheets into the body of an email and send it to a group. Is it possible to automate this? And if it is, is it possible to go even further and skip out any rows where the value in the A column is 'DONT EMAIL THIS ROW'

I've seen some examples where they can be sent as an attachment but I would really like it to be in the body. Thanks, John

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function emailA1D20() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet76');
  var rg=sh.getRange('A1:D20');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var html='<table>';
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]!='DONT EMAIL THIS ROW') {
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>', vA[i][0], vA[i][1], vA[i][2], vA[i][3]);
    }
  }
  html+='</table>';
  var recipient='emailaddress'
  var subject="Sending A1:D20"
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, null, {htmlBody:html});
}
```

I tested this and it worked for me.

- [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Gmail Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)

Comment: Wow, thats awesome, thank you. Don't suppose there is anyway to keep the formatting as well (we have very clear Green/Red cells so people can see what is outstanding. Being able to get that as well would be perfect. But if not, this is very useful and I thank you

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to copy and paste it.